# A Statement in a Thesis Proposal

Tags: research-process, thesis

In a paper an author developed a weight function. I am doing M.S Thesis and trying to incorporate the weight function in another function. In my thesis proposal if I mention

> We will incorporate the weight function developed for selected ranked set sampling design into Equation (6)

, is it proper way to write the sentence? Will I mention `We will try...` instead of `We will...`?

Comment: You said "Thesis Proposal" in the title. You then said "M.S Thesis" There is a difference between a proposal and the actual thesis. Please clarify.

Comment: @scaaahu I am at Proposal stage of the thesis.

Comment: Then I must have a question here. How would you know that Equation (6) would be Equation (6)? Not Equation (5) or (7)?

Comment: @scaaahu  Equation (6) is a general formula. Here weight function is involved. And the weight function varies from one sampling design to another.